# War File not Deployed Correctly on Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, war

I have a war file that is working correctly under my local Tomcat 8 installation. It also runs fine when ran with jetty-runner.

Unfortunately, when deployed to Heroku using "heroku deploy:war" with the Heroku Toolbelt, it doesn't work as expected. Static files are accessible, and listeners defined in our web.xml file are executed. However, no servlets are accessible.

The web.xml file looks like this. It is thought that this file is at fault because MyResourceConfig (which extends org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig) is never initialized.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>foo.bar.MyResourceConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>foo.bar.Listener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: What happens when you run locally with [webapp-runner](https://github.com/jsimone/webapp-runner)? That's what Heroku uses. If you'd like to use jetty-runner, you can include it in the slug, but you'll need to define your own Procfile.

Comment: Post the heroku logs as wel!

Comment: It turns out that using the Procfile with the Jetty Runner solved the problem. Thank you!